# Forcing single result as array in JSON output

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

I am retrieving inventory data from a SQL database, this i want to be transformed into JSON for further processing.

There are separate queries for Operating System, Processors and Applications (Add&Remove Information).

For the OS usually one row is returned, for processors there is either one or more lines, and for applications there is usually a couple lines.

Retrieval of data is done like this (this part works fine):

```
$deviceOperatingSystem = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $sqlServer -Database $sqlDatabase -Query $inventoryOperatingSystemQuery -credential $databaseCredentials -Variable $variables
$deviceProcessors = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $sqlServer -Database $sqlDatabase -Query $inventoryProcessorsQuery -credential $databaseCredentials -Variable $variables
$deviceApplications = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $sqlServer -Database $sqlDatabase -Query $inventoryApplicationsQuery -credential $databaseCredentials -Variable $variables
```

it is then fed to an array like this:

```
$deviceInventoryOutput = @()
    $deviceInventoryOutput += [PSCustomObject]@{
        'OperatingSystem'    = $deviceOperatingSystem
        'Processors'         = $deviceProcessors     
        'Applications'       = $deviceApplications   
                    }
```

and the output looks like this:

```
{
    "OperatingSystem":  {
                            "Caption":  "Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise",
                            "Version":  "10.0.16299",
                            "BuildNumber":  "16299",
                            "ServicePackMajorVersion":  0,
                            "Language":  1031
                        },
    "Processors":  {
                       "Name":  "Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6100U CPU @ 2.30GHz",
                       "Description":  "Intel64 Family 6 Model 78 Stepping 3",
                       "Manufacturer":  "GenuineIntel",
                       "NumberOfCores":  1,
                       "NumberOfLogicalCores":  1
                   },
    "Applications":  [
                         {
                             "Name":  "IM.order",
                             "Publisher":  "Ingram Micro Distribution GmbH",
                             "Version":  "6.41.761.0"
                         },
                         {
                             "Name":  "JTL-Wawi",
                             "Publisher":  "JTL-Software-GmbH",
                             "Version":  "1.2.3.7"
                         },...
}
```

the receiving API expects the information for processors as an array, even if there is only one entry, so my example should actually look like this:

```
{
    "Processors":  [{
                       "Name":  "Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6100U CPU @ 2.30GHz",
                       "Description":  "Intel64 Family 6 Model 78 Stepping 3",
                       "Manufacturer":  "GenuineIntel",
                       "NumberOfCores":  1,
                       "NumberOfLogicalCores":  1
                   }]
}
```

i tried to wrap the processors variable like this

```
'Processors'         = @($deviceProcessors)
```

but this didn't help much.i also tried initializing the $deviceProcessors as an array like:

```
$deviceProcessors = @()
$deviceProcessors += Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $sqlServer -Database $sqlDatabase -Query $inventoryProcessorsQuery -credential $databaseCredentials -Variable $variables
```

but also, nope didn't work out.

```
 $deviceProcessors.GetType() returns System.Data.DataRow
 $deviceApplications.GetType() returns System.Object[]
```

The expected output should have [] around the information for the processors if only one result is returned from the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code snippet should do the job:

```
$deviceInventoryOutput = @()
$deviceInventoryOutput += [PSCustomObject]@{
    'OperatingSystem'    = $deviceOperatingSystem
    'Processors'         = $deviceProcessors     
    'Applications'       = $deviceApplications   
}
# possible additional `$deviceInventoryOutput += [PSCustomObject]@{…}` here

for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $deviceInventoryOutput.Count; $i++ ) {
  foreach ( $aux in $( $deviceInventoryOutput[$i] | 
                            Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty ).Name ) {
      if ( $deviceInventoryOutput[$i].$aux.Gettype().name -ne 'Object[]' ) {
          $deviceInventoryOutput[$i].$aux = @($deviceInventoryOutput[$i].$aux)
      }
  }
}
$deviceInventoryOutput | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 2
```

Comment: That works beautifully, one question:
`for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $deviceInventoryOutput.Count; $i++ ) {...}`
is used in case there is more than one "device" in the output, correct?

Comment: @xBarns Correct. For instance, if one collects data from more than one SQL servers…